# Is there granger causality that can be applied to panel data with structural breaks?

Tags: macroeconomics, time-series, paneldata

I have panel data containing various macroeconomic variables (for example: interest rate, output, unemployment).

I would like to run a Granger causality test on some of them, but there are structural breaks in the data.  Is there any similar test applicable to panel data with structural breaks?